# Angular inject translate in link directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translation, inject

I have two files, an Angular directive and the Controller.
The Controller has the translate function injected, but I need to inject it into the Directive for some translations I want to do right there.
The problem is, each time I try to inject the translate module, it just won't do it. (I have the strings defined on another file, I'm guessing that's not the problem.)
My code looks like this so far:

```
appmod = angular.module('directive', []);
appmod.directive('gvPivot', ['$translate', function() {
    return {
            restrict : "E",
            replace : true,
            scope : {
                name : "@",
                data : "="
            },
            template : '',
            link : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn, translate) {
                scope.$watch("data", function(newValue, oldValue, translate) {
                    console.log('{{ "Translated text" | translate}}');
```

The result I expect is that it logs the "translated text" to the language.

But what it logs is

```
{{ "Text to translate" | translate}}
```

I am aware that I have probably injected the translate way too often in way too many incorrect places, but as of now I am just doing the shotgun approach and trying to insert it anywhere it might fit.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to translate the text, by also injecting $filter.

```
appmod.directive('gvPivot', ['$translate', '$filter', function($translate, $filter) {
return {
        restrict : "E",
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            name: "@",
            data : "="
        },
        template : '',
        link : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
            console.log($filter('translate')('translate this'));
```